# What's the easiest way to grab a web page in C?

Tags: c, sockets, html

I'm working on an old school linux variant (QNX to be exact) and need a way to grab a web page (no cookies or login, the target URL is just a text file) using nothing but sockets and arrays.

Anyone got a snippet for this?

note: I don't control the server and I've got very little to work with besides what is already on the box (adding in additional libraries is not really "easy" given the contraints -- although I do love libcurl)

Comment: Can you guarantee no proxies, no SSL, no gzip? And do you control the server?

Comment: you said using nothing but sockets and arrays, but if you want to reconsider, use wget and pipe its output to a file handler:
FILE *fp=popen("wget --quiet -O - http://www.google.com","r")

Comment: Unimportant, but since when is QNX a Linux variant? They're both Unix-like, but AFAIK there's no direct relationship between them. QNX is a microkernel, and Linus famously dislikes those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do have some code, but it also supports (Open)SSL so it's a bit long to post here.

In essence:

- parse the URL (split out URL scheme, host name, port number, scheme specific part
- create the socket:

  `s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, proto);`
- populate a `sockaddr_in` structure with the remote IP and port
- connect the socket to the far end:

  `err = connect(s, &addr, sizeof(addr));`
- make the request string:

  `n = snprinf(headers, "GET /%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", ...);`
- send the request string:

  `write(s, headers, n);`
- read the data:

  `while (n = read(s, buffer, bufsize) > 0) {
      ...
  }`
- close the socket:

  `close(s);`

nb: pseudo-code above would collect both response headers *and* data.   The split between the two is the first blank line.

Comment: You appear to be missing the request, i.e. sending the GET /blah.htm.

Comment: I was adding it as you posted your comment

Comment: Nice detailed answer, +1 (maybe put the SSL code on pastebin?)

Comment: PLEASE post your snippet that also supports SSL

Comment: I'll see what I can do - it's somewhat old and probably needs some more comments adding if it's going to be shown publicly :)

Answer (score 10):

I'd look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) if you want SSL support for or anything fancy.

However if you just want to get a simple webpage from a port 80, then just open a tcp socket, send "`GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\r\n\r`" and parse the output.

Comment: rE: libcurl - and add mostly likely several 100 KB and goodness knows how many library dependencies to your program's executable...

Comment: I'm getting `400 - Bad Request` when doing this.

Comment: Please not that my answer was written in 2009. If the web-server supports HTTP 1.0 this should still work. But it's getting harder and harder to find sites that do not require TLS these days.

The accepted answer is your best bet. Otherwise try some client libs.